# @ModelAttribute dependency check not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

The @ModelAttribute methods in the controller are

```
@ModelAttribute("command")
public A getA() {
...
}

@ModelAttribute
public void prepareData(@ModelAttribute("command") A a) {
...
}
```

We are using Spring 4.2.6 version and [As per Spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/39268-what-order-are-annotated-methods-called-in) This issue has been resolved in 4.1.0 version of spring. When I deploy the project sometimes getA() is executing before prepareData and sometimes prepareData() is executing before getA(), but according to [jira for above issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6299), it has been fixed in all the spring versions starting from 4.1.0. Could you please suggest am I missing anything here.

Answer (score 2):

You should mark only 'preparedData' with @ModelAttribute not both. Marking so means it would get executed before any requests or controller method is called.

So if 'getA' is your controller method and you want to preprocess 'A' before it being called (at getA) your methods should be something like this

```
public A getA(@ModelAttribute("command") A a) { ... }

@ModelAttribute("command")
public A prepareData() { 
  return new A();//or some other way you want to populate values of A
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please go through these links https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6299 and also can you please check the test case available here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/56a82c1cbe8276408f9fff06cfb1ac9da7961a80

Comment: @ModelAttribute("foo") & @ModelAttribute("bar") are different from each other

Comment: But getBar is taking parameter as foo if you observe

Comment: @Irfan this should work perfectly, model attributes are depending on each other but it not the same objects

Comment: So you mean i can have any no. of methods annotated with modelattribute and can have inter dependency and should return something as below                                                @ModelAttribute("foo")
public Object getFoo() {
    ...
}
 
@ModelAttribute("bar")
public Object getBar(@ModelAttribute("foo") Object foo) {
  if( some condition of foo ){
    do stuff
  }
}

Comment: Yep you should be able to

Comment: I tried as above but it is not working @ModelAttribute("command") public MyObj getCommand() {...} @ModelAttribute("listabc") List<ABC> getListABC(@ModelAttribute("command") MyObj obj) {...}. getListABC is calling before getcommand.